# Angular UI Bootstrap alert is not closing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have copied angular Uis example and it is not closing.
Despite the fact that my close function is being called etc and have also tried setting the alert to null manually and no luck.

HTML:

```
<alert ng-repeat="alert in cantVoteWhenNotLoggedInAlerts" 
    type="alert.type"
    close="closeCantVoteWhenNotLoggedInAlert($index)">{{ alert.msg }
</alert>
```

JavaScript:

```
//add
$scope.cantVoteWhenNotLoggedInAlerts.push({
  type: 'warning',
  msg: 'Must be logged in'
});                                

$scope.closeCantVoteWhenNotLoggedInAlert = function (index) {
  $scope.cantVoteWhenNotLoggedInAlerts.splice(index, 1);
};
```

Comment: It seems alright, can you post a jsfiddle ?

Comment: Your code works. Here is the Js Fiddle.         https://jsfiddle.net/alaksandarjesus/j9ks1uc6/

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, It's working

```
<alert ng-repeat="alert in cantVoteWhenNotLoggedInAlerts" type="alert.type"
      ng-click="closeCantVoteWhenNotLoggedInAlert(this)">{{ alert.msg }}</alert>


$scope.closeCantVoteWhenNotLoggedInAlert = function (this) {
            $scope.cantVoteWhenNotLoggedInAlerts.splice(this.$index, 1);
        };
```

Comment: Not for me, shouldn't pass 'this' in as a parameter anyway? Perhaps it's because my alert is within an ng re-peat already